# Account limit reached when attempting to create a new Apple ID

Tags: ipad, apple-id

I am trying to create a new Apple ID and now it's telling me: "account limit reached"

Answer (score 1):

If you reset your iPad, in the open dialogue boxes, skip the apple id sign in. When you reach the home screen, open settings and log in your apple id. Then you can begin purchasing again. But since this is your first time to purchase, make sure use different credit card.